# What is the difference between Microsoft SQL Server Connection and Generic DB connection provided in DB connector from Mule 4.3?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-component, mule4

In the current project we are already using generic db connection and now we found that there is Sql Serve connection available but we have never used that so want to explore that option.

Is it going to give better performance than generic connection?

One observation from my experience is Generic Connection is working for Windows Authentication where as SqlServer Connection is not working for the same and working for Sql Account.

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft SQL Server Connection](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.10/database-documentation#config_mssql) provides some database specific configurations to simplify the configuration of the connection. For example an instance name. With the Generic Connection you can only use generic JDBC configurations. There should not be a difference in performance. Depending on how did you configure Windows Authentication in the generic connection it may or not be possible to replicate it in the Microsoft SQL Server Connection. If you are happy with your current connection configuration there is no need to change it.